# Literal contains unmatched quote

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a numeric parameter given to my macro and would like to convert it to date, set to end of month and apply a format.

Following code works for many dates, but not for march; throws 'Literal contains unmatched quote'.

```
proc format;
   picture mydatep
   low-high = "'%0d-%0b-%0Y'" (datatype = date);

%macro test(cycle=);

   %let enddate = %SYSFUNC(intnx(month, %SYSFUNC(inputn(&cycle., yymmn6.)), 0, e), mydatep.);
   %put &enddate.;

%mend;

%test(cycle=201602); /* works --> 29-Feb-2016*/
%test(cycle=201603); /* works not */
%test(cycle=201604); /* works again --> 30-Apr-2016*/

%test(cycle=201402); /* works --> 28-Feb-2014*/
%test(cycle=201403); /* works not */
%test(cycle=201404); /* works again --> 30-Apr-2014*/
```

I have been using the code for some years now, and never had trouble with it. I am using SAS Analytics Pro 9.4

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code - well, nothing other than it has more quotes than it needs, the `"'..."'` is excessive, just use `' '` - and really should have a `run` or `quit` after the `proc format`, but that code pasted into SAS runs fine.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I removed the " as you suggested. Now, I don't receive an error anymore, however, the output for a march date is now 31-Mar-201, i.e. the last digit of the year is missing. Besides, do you have a clue, why march is invoking suc weird behaviour in the two cases?

Comment: It isn't, something else is the issue on your side. Run this is a new session and you shouldn't see any issues. How are you creating the macro variables/passing them in?

Comment: Thanks @Reeza, I used SAS (Unicode). I switched to SAS (German) and it works fine, now. But to answer your question, I was executing the exact code from above.

Comment: Note that because of the missing RUN statement to end the PROC FORMAT step the macro code is going to use some previous definition of the format (if it exists) and not the one created by the first three lines.  That is because the PROC FORMAT code will not have run when the macro code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I was starting the SAS session via SAS (Unicode). Switching to SAS (Deutsch) [engl: SAS (German)], solved the issue.

I don't know why, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you used an endash or emdash instead of hyphens in your PICTURE text that would change the generated character string from 12 bytes to 13 or 14 bytes.  Those non ASCII characters require more than one byte of storage.

So if your code used a width of 12 with that format then the value would be truncated removing the closing quote and possibly the last digit of the year also.

Tell PROC FORMAT that the default width for the format should be 14 and not 13.

```
proc format;
   picture mydatep (default=14)
   low-high = "'%0d-%0b-%0Y'" (datatype = date);
run;
```

Example:

```
23   proc options option=ENCODING option=LOCALE option=DATESTYLE option=DFLANG ;
24   run;

    SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M5

 ENCODING=UTF-8    Specifies the default character-set encoding for the SAS session.
 LOCALE=EN_US      Specifies a set of attributes in a SAS session that reflect the language, local conventions, and culture for a
                   geographical region.
 DATESTYLE=MDY     Specifies the sequence of month, day, and year when ANYDTDTE, ANYDTDTM, or ANYDTTME informat data is ambiguous.
 DFLANG=GERMAN     Specifies the language for international date informats and formats.
NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


25
26   options dflang=german locale=de_DE ;
27
28   data test;
29     do month=1 to 12;
30       length string $20 ;
31       string=put(mdy(month,1,2000),mydatep.);
32       put month= string=;
33     end;
34   run;

month=1 string='01-Jan-2000'
month=2 string='01-Feb-2000'
month=3 string='01-Mär-2000
month=4 string='01-Apr-2000'
month=5 string='01-Mai-2000'
month=6 string='01-Jun-2000'
month=7 string='01-Jul-2000'
month=8 string='01-Aug-2000'
month=9 string='01-Sep-2000'
month=10 string='01-Okt-2000'
month=11 string='01-Nov-2000'
month=12 string='01-Dez-2000'
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


35   proc format;
36      picture mydatep (default=14)
37      low-high = "'%0d-%0b-%0Y'" (datatype = date);
NOTE: Format MYDATEP is already on the library WORK.FORMATS.
NOTE: Format MYDATEP has been output.
38   run;

NOTE: PROZEDUR FORMAT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


39
40   data test;
41     do month=1 to 12;
42       length string $20 ;
43       string=put(mdy(month,1,2000),mydatep.);
44       put month= string=;
45     end;
46   run;

month=1 string='01-Jan-2000'
month=2 string='01-Feb-2000'
month=3 string='01-Mär-2000'
month=4 string='01-Apr-2000'
month=5 string='01-Mai-2000'
month=6 string='01-Jun-2000'
month=7 string='01-Jul-2000'
month=8 string='01-Aug-2000'
month=9 string='01-Sep-2000'
month=10 string='01-Okt-2000'
month=11 string='01-Nov-2000'
month=12 string='01-Dez-2000'
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kenji: "Switching to SAS (Deutsch) [engl: SAS (German)], solved the issue. I don't know why, though."
The explanation is quite simple, some date formats in German and English differ in just a few cases:

```
 German        English       equal?
 ----------------------------------------
 01Jan2022     01Jan2022     yes
 01Feb2022     01Feb2022     yes
 01Mär2022     01Mar2022     NO
 01Apr2022     01Apr2022     yes
 ...
 01Okt2022     01Oct2022     NO
 01Nov2022     01Nov2022     yes
 01Dez2022     01Dec2022     NO
```

So in a German environment, it is a common observation that your code might work in most cases but not for March, October and December.

Comment: I answered that already in my other post.  The value you show for the German version of March is using a non 7-bit ASCII character in place of the lowercase a that the English version users.  So the length of the generated string is going to be longer.  So if the format is defined with a default width that is only long enough display `'01-MAR-2011'` and you try to display `'01-Mär-2022'` instead then the extra bytes required to represent `ä` will mean that some of the characters at the end will be removed.  Including the closing quote, leading to SAS code that has unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Show the values of the ENCODING, LOCALE, DATESTYLE and DFLANG system options for the two different SAS sessions.